# Advanced Search/Smart Group returning wrong results based on participant role (CiviEvent participant roles overlap?)

Tags: civievent, search, smartgroups, search-results, custom-search

We have a number of participant roles setup in CiviEvent, with IDs ranging from 1-10.  This includes a "Participant" role with ID 1 and "Sponsor" role with ID of 10 (and various roles with IDs 2-9 in between).  The Sponsor role is not counted, all other roles are counted.

When I run a search for contacts with the only criteria being Participant Role = Sponsor, I get the one contact currently assigned to that role.

When I run a search for contacts with the only criteria being Participant Role = Participant, I get all of the contacts assigned to that role, **PLUS** the contact who has the role Sponsor on one event.

I have triple checked and the "Sponsor" contact only has one event and his only role in that event is Sponsor.  He should not be showing up for the search where the only role selected is Participant.

The only thing I can think of is that the search criteria is erroneously returning any ID with "1" in it?

Any other thoughts or ideas?

---

Running on WordPress / CiviCRM 4.6.10

Comment: is it the same if you search via Search Builder?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Very strange.

Comment: We're having the same issue. Did you find a solution?